# Find the value of the periodic continued fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, continued-fractions

> Find the value of the periodic continued fraction with the terms
>   $1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, . . .$

We see that it starts to be periodic after $1$ = $q_0$, i.e, $3,4,3,2$ then  $3,4,3,2$ etc...

I know that $x= \frac{A_{k+1}}{B_{k+1}}$ = $\frac{A_{k-1}+y.A_K}{B_{k-1}+y.B_K}$ where $q_{k+1}=y$

but then how do I find my number $x$ = continued fraction?

Answer (score 1):

You have $$X={3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{X}}}}}$$ for the periodic part.  If you use your formula to compute the right-hand side, you will end up with a quadratic in $X$.  Solve for $X$ and note that $X$ must be positive.  Don't forget to add in the $1$ at the end.

Comment: I solved for $x$ and I got $5x^2-14x-7=0$. Then I did $1+\frac1x$ and I got the same quadratic equation. Is it correct?

Comment: @cbcbc That isn't what I got.  Update your answer to show your calculations, and I'll take a look at them.